# Can swashbuckle serialize one swagger document as v2 but the others as v3?

Tags: sdk, openapi, swashbuckle

According to the documentation [Here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#serialize-swagger-in-the-20-format) setting the `SerializeAsV2` option can render all of your swagger documents as v2.

Because there are some tools we use to generate SDKs, one of which is having issues with generating against openapi3 (but works with v2) so for a short term fix I was hoping to be able to render a singular document as v2 and leave the others defaulting to openapi3.

Has anyone had any experience trying to do something like this?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Ultimately we did not find a work around for that specific issue. We ended up going with a completely different sdk generator that was not having issues with OpenApi3